# Finagle Send request to random server within cluster

Tags: finagle, twitter-finagle

I am using `finagle` as `rest` client. In `ClientBuilder` I specify a range of hosts, but the request requires setting a url with host.
How can I avoid specifying host in the request and let finagle choose one ?
Thanks.

```
    val client = ClientBuilder().hosts("host1:81,host2:82").codec(Http()).build()

    val request = RequestBuilder()
        // .url("http://host1/get") // dont want to specify host
        // .url("/get") // MalformedURLException: no protocol
        .buildGet()

    var resp = client(request) // sent to host specified by url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using `finagle-http` module. It's not possible to build request without host in URL using `RequestBuilder`. Still, you can construct `Request` manually (or create your own RequestBuilder for further use)

I'd recommend however switching to `finagle-httpx` module (https://github.com/twitter/finagle/tree/develop/finagle-httpx). It's not compatible with `finagle-http`, but it has lots of API improvements and the ability to create requests without host in URL in among them, for example:

```
val client = Httpx.client.withTls("my.api")
  .newService("host1.my.api:443,host2.my.api:443")

val req = Request("/get")

val rep = client(req)
```